# Make Simultaneous HTTP Requests That Resolve Into a Single Return

Tags: javascript, jquery, interview-questions, asynchronous, ajax

This week, in an ongoing job search, I was tasked with the following pre-screening question:

> Make two simultaneous http requests. Use the language and library of your choice. Make sure the results are combined and resolve into a single return.

For this I chose JavaScript and jQuery, culminating in the following [Gist](https://gist.github.com/drew-beres/275cd1b76574497327761b33fb08ad4d) and [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/gist/jquery/edge/275cd1b76574497327761b33fb08ad4d/).

fiddle.js:

```
var gistID = '275cd1b76574497327761b33fb08ad4d';

function Source(url){
 this.url = url;
};

var source = new Source("/gh/gist/response.html/" + gistID + "/");
var sources = [source,source];

function asyncGroup() {

 var promises = [];

 sources.forEach(function(source,index,sources){

  var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();

  promises.push(deferred.promise());

  $.ajax({url: source.url, processData: false}).always(function(data){
   sources[index].element = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' + data + '"/>';
   deferred.resolve();
  });
 });
 return promises;
}

$.when.apply(null, asyncGroup() ).done(function( status ) {

 sources.forEach(function(source){$("#myDiv").append($(source.element));});
 $("#myDiv").show();
});
```

One thing I would like to change is to accredit Fiddle Author Casiano Rodriguez-Leon for their [base64 testing image](http://jsfiddle.net/casiano/xadvz/), provided it remains in the implementation. Perhaps this is best done in [fiddle.manifest](https://gist.github.com/drew-beres/275cd1b76574497327761b33fb08ad4d#file-fiddle-manifest), I am not sure.

Beyond that, I know that much can be improved, and I'm all ears.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compatibility aside, you can skip jQuery. Everything you need is present in vanilla JS. jQuery AJAX can be replaced by [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) and deferreds can be replaced by native [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). As an added bonus, use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to easily construct strings.

```
// Work on the very basic data, the IDs
const ids = [
  '275cd1b76574497327761b33fb08ad4d',
  '275cd1b76574497327761b33fb08ad4d'
];

// Map IDs into urls
const urls = ids.map(id => `/gh/gist/response.html/${id}/`);

// Construct a function that transforms the Response object into an img
const responseToImage = res => `<img src="data:image/png;base64,${res.text()}"/>`;

// For each, send request, convert response to img, and store promise in array
const promises = urls.map(url => fetch(url).then(responseToImage));

// Wait until all promises resolve, then append image
Promise.all(promises).then(images => {
  const container = $('#myDiv').show();
  images.forEach(image => container.append(image));
});
```

---

As for your code, a few things

```
var gistID = '275cd1b76574497327761b33fb08ad4d';

function Source(url){
 this.url = url;
};

var source = new Source("/gh/gist/response.html/" + gistID + "/");
var sources = [source,source];
```

This code doesn't look scalable. If say I wanted to add more images, different images, there is no way for this code to do that without having to modify several lines of code. In this case, `gistId` has to be abandoned, you'd have to write `new Source(...)` for each item, and update the `sources` array.

Also, insider tip: It's a bad sign if a really simple code update results in modification of several lines. Also, writing code this way results to bad habits which can hurt in the long run.

```
function asyncGroup() {

 var promises = [];

 sources.forEach(function(source,index,sources){

  var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();

  promises.push(deferred.promise());

  $.ajax({url: source.url, processData: false}).always(function(data){
   sources[index].element = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' + data + '"/>';
   deferred.resolve();
  });
 });
 return promises;
}
```

The `$.ajax` function already returns a Deferred-like, [jqXHR](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) object. You don't need to "wrap" it in a Deferred, this is already redundant. You can simply push its return value to the array. Additionally, when doing `1:1` conversion from one array to another, [`array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is the function you want. With these, you can remove all that boilerplate code to transform `source.url` to an array of deferreds.

```
$.when.apply(null, asyncGroup() ).done(function( status ) {
 sources.forEach(function(source){$("#myDiv").append($(source.element));});
 $("#myDiv").show();
});
```

You can cache the result of `$('#myDiv')` in a variable so that you don't have to call it repeatedly. Additionally, [`jquery.append`](https://api.jquery.com/append/) accepts HTML strings as argument. No need to convert it first.